# Point of intersection

Tags: sql, postgis, spatial

I am using postgis for my spatial database.

in my database I have a set of lines in one table and a set of points in another table. How Is it possible to determine which fits best as a point of intersection of two lines? What i am after is something related to the st_intersection function.

Comment: Interesting question but not enough info. Can you add some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Basically i have a set of linestrings which are of type geometry and the desired output would be that point which intersect both lines.

Answer (score 0):

PostGIS's `ST_INTERSECTION` will give you the geometry of the point of intersection between the two lines, and then a `MIN(ST_DISTANCE([...], [...])` between this intersection and your points will give you the best fit.

> - http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersection.html
> - http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance.html